# Android how to keep application running even when Phone is locked

Tags: android, call

I am trying to make an IP-Phone Application using UDP, the App Works like a charm, i was wondering if i could somehow keep it running even when the user locks the phone is it possible and how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Google yielded no results at all?

Comment: A `Service` may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `Service`.

> A Service is an application component representing either an
>   application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not
>   interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other
>   applications to use.

Comment: so instead of using an `Activity` i use a `Service` ?

Comment: No, you use a `Service` along with an `Activity`.